# How do I move the mouse pointer in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, ide

How do I move my mouse in selenium IDE? E.g. a command moving the mouse pointer 14 pixels to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium IDE is a record and play application. It wasn't design to allow people performing other complex things, just record and play (and manage locators that can change).
If you want to do more complex things, you can try to use Selenium with an OOP language (java, c#, ruby, python etc).